# Downloading Code from TFSPreview

Tags: c#, tfs

We are using the TFS Preview for the version control.
But the problem is, we don't have any backup for that server.

What we wonna do is the following.
On a server we wonna schedule some application. That download all TeamProjects
into a folder ( each day another folder ) 20121104 / 20121204 / 201213/04 / ...
So we have always the code from last night.

I found a couple things , like workspace.Get() , .....

What is the best solution.

PS: The writing language is C#

Comment: This may be a silly question but why would you want to locally back up a cloud offering? The whole purpose of using cloud services is to take care of common problems like backups.

Comment: Because in the "Terms and Conditions" on the site of TFS Preview stands that they can delete the content in this preview state. So it's  important to have some backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple solutions,

You can install local TFS and sync it with with TFS Service using [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe), and run a schedule backup against your local one, this also will help you so if the internet connection not available for any reason you will continue to work

Another solution to create scheduled task that has a batch file or power shell script that run to get latest

You can also create a build definition that its trigger a scheduled and customize the build to get the source and put it in your local machine

**Updated**

[image]

Comment: That TFS Integration Tools tool is only to migrate your code? You can't use that to syncronize your code? How do you use the powershell to do that?